# Permission error while browsing the Dimension when Dimension Security is defined on one of the attribute

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimensional-modeling

I am using SSAS SQL Server for dimension modelling, and the dimension is defined as below:

Dimension Name: Department

Dimension Attributes:

```
 Location
 DepartmentCode
 DepartmentType
```

I have dimension security defined on one of the attribute, i.e., on Location (not on the main Department dimension) using the Factless Fact Dimension Security.

When I try to execute the following MDX query (to retrieve all the Level 0 members of the Department Dimension along with the DepartmentCode Attribute), I get the error as "Errors in the OLAP storage engine: Either you do not have permission to access the specified member, or the specified member does not exist.":

```
SELECT {} ON 0, { [Department].Levels(0) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES [Department].[DepartmentCode] ON 1 
FROM SampleCube
```

I am able to successfully browse Location Attribute using the following MDX query provided the user has access to Location:

```
SELECT {} ON 0, { [Location].[All].Children } ON 1 FROM SampleCube
```

Any Idea on what might be going wrong when I browse the main dimension with DepartmentCode attribute? Browsing without DepartmentCode attribute works fine. Please do let me know if you need any information..

Comment: Can you show us the MDX used to define your security? I suspect the issue is there. Does it work when you connect as an administrator?